# How can I find all <a> tags that match a certain pattern?

Tags: javascript, dom, queryselector

I want to match all `a` tags that have `example.com/app` in the `href`. How can I do this with JavaScript?

Comment: so make a selector that matches the attribute with a contains https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll("a[href*='example.com/app']")`

Comment: See https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `querySelectorAll` with a [css attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

```
document.querySelectorAll('a[href="www.example.com"]')
```

Comment: Is this the most performant way?

Comment: @Shamoon i suppose that more than a "native" way there is not, but i've not tested it against other "algorithmic" way, but surely is the more cleaner and maintanable

Answer (score 1):

You can select all `a` elements then check if they have `href` with a value of `example.com/app`:

```js
const a = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
let els = [];

for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  if ((a[i].getAttribute("href") == "example.com/app") || (a[i].getAttribute("href") == "https://example.com/app")) {
    els.push(a[i]);
  }
}

console.log(els);
```

```html
<a href="example.com/app" id="1">1</a>
<a href="https://example.com/app" id="2">2</a>
<a href="example.com/app" id="3">3</a>
<a href="" id="4">4</a>
<a id="5">5</a>
<a href="https://example.com/app" class="6">6</a>
<a href="https://example.com/app">7</a>
```